# about axios ，how can I add a headers params in a request with abbreviation

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios

So ,i am doing a project that i have to add a headers params in a request ,how can i add it in short codes?
i first use the method below:

```js
const { data: { data } } = await refeshToken.put('/v1_0/authorizations', {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${user.refresh_token}`
        }
      })
```

the result shows that: the header did not add
and i chosed second method like:

```js
const { data: { data } } = await refeshToken.put('/v1_0/authorizations', {}, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${user.refresh_token}`
        }
      })
```

the only difference is i add a {} in my codes and it worked.
I realy curious about it, I hope someone can answer it.
I realy want to know what i can write in these '{}'
what i konw is that:

```js
{
   params:{xxx}
}
```

means the request params in your request

```js
{
  xxx:xxx
}
```

means the Request Body Parameters
what else params in axios?
thank you for your answering!!!

what i realy expected to happen is that the request should success since i did in my first method:

```js
const { data: { data } } = await refeshToken.put('/v1_0/authorizations', {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${user.refresh_token}`
        }
      })
```

i do not know why it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Look at [the documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosputurl-data-config).

The second argument is the data you are PUTting. You can put whatever data you like (so long at the URL you are PUTting it to expects that type of data).

The third argument is the config.

Headers are part of the config. If you put that config object as the second argument then it will be treated as the data you at PUTting instead of as the config.

Comment: i got it,another question: what if i want to add a query params where should i put it ?another '{params}' before data argument?

Comment: Query parameters go in the URL.

Comment: thank you so much for spenting time on this, not only justify my codes and answer my question! i got it how to write it right now